# Flutter how to refactor large a stateful widget into smaller ones

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm writing an app with one very large stateful widget, It is composed of three main sections in the UI, so I want to have it refactored into 3 different widgets. However, each of the 3 widgets has a shared "selectedColor" variable which ch anges the color of all three widgets. VS Code won't let me refactor the widgets because they setState, so It will just throw an error if I try to setState. Basically If all the code is one big chunk, it's fine, but how can I refactor my code into 3 widgets while being able to setstatethe colors of all three? Thanks - Joseph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method in the each of the seperate widgets which set the state of the respective widget. Then, create objects of the widgets in the main class, add to the UI and call the methods from there.

```
class Mainclass extends StatelessWidget{
widget1 obj = new widget1();
..
..

Widget build(BuildContext context){

return obj;

}


void setstate(){
obj.set();
}
```

And then, widget1's code should be somewhat like:

```
class widget1 extends StatefulWidget{

widget1State st = new widget1State();

void set(){
  st.setSt();
}
State<StatefulWidget> createState() => st;

}

class widget1State extends State<widget1>{

void setSt(){
setState((){

});
}
..
..
}
```

Comment: This is the best I could do.... Pls tell if there is a better way.